# Laravel login always return 1 user

Tags: php, laravel

I use Laravel 4 and Auth::attempt() like this code:

```
$cred = array(
                'email'     => Input::get('email'),
                'password'  => Input::get('password'),
                'active'    => 1, //user must be activated before
            );
            if (Auth::attempt($cred, false)) 
            {
                // the auth.attempt event will be fired
                return Redirect::to(URL::action('Admin@index'));
            }
```

and it works fine but when I call user email with command

```
Auth::user()->email;
```

It always return the first user in the Users table even I have logged in with other user's cred.

for example, If I have multiple users in DB, then even I send cred of user2 or user3 it always return user1.

Comment: Everything seems fine to me, make sure you are making log out the current user before you log in and browser cache is cleared, but sounds odd, indeed.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of two issues that can cause this:

#### Session

```
Auth::user();
```

accesses the user session in order to get the token from which it can identify the user in the model, so flush the session and try to login with the other users, using:

```
Session::flush();
```

#### Database

I would want to go to the database to make sure everything is under the logic expectations, take a look at a couple of rows of the user table, especially the ID column and the Email.

i don't think that this should be considered as a direct answer, rather than where to look and what might cause the problem, hope it works out with you!